# Cosmetic Glitches in Okular in Fedora 33 KDE

Tags: fedora, kde, okular

Okular shows "No Text" in place of "File" and other menu items in the top menu bar. See screenshot. I've tried removing and reinstalling the program to no success. What's causing this and how do I fix it?
[image]

Further system info:
[image]

Comment: maybe it means something

Comment: search the folders that relate to Okular for `No text` .... btw, you said `No Text`, but the picture shows `No text` ... always try to be accurate

Comment: lol...good catch...I guess. But do you have an actual solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug in Okular](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=395497). Removing `~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/okular/shell.rc` should fix it. Some people mentioned removing only the config option `noMerge="1"` from this file also fixes the problem.

(I was able to reproduce the behaviour with steps from [comment #4](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=395497#c4) and removing the file helped.)

Comment: This worked, thanks. For my information, being new to Linux systems, how does one access the files/config options you mention above?